# llamar bootstrap modal desde el code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Tengo una pagina en aspx que contiene un modal de bootstrap 4

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalExito" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Información</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Registro grabado</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Aceptar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

En el codigo de la pagina tengo la siguiente funcion que muestra el modal:

```
function showModalExito() {
        $("#modalExito").modal("show");
    }
```

y en el code behind estoy tratando de llamar el modal dentro de un evento click de un boton asp de la siguiente forma:

```
script = "$(function() { showModalExito(); }); ";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "btnLCDAscript", script, true);
```

El modal no se muestra y me sale un error "'$' no está definido"

¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: el code behind se esta ejecutando en el servidor, y el modal esta en la pc del usuario. Vos tendrias que avisarle de alguna forma en la respuesta para que muestre el modal. desde atras no lo vas a poder mostrar nunca.

Comment: en que contexto defines el `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` ? esta en el evento de un boton, o donde? el que no reconozca el $ indica que la carga del js de jquery no se esta realizando.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini el scriptmanager esta en el evento click del boton asp

Comment: Estas referenciando bien el jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se genera porque el `RegisterStartupScript()` pone ese codigo en el `header` del html y seguramente lo esta definiendo antes que el codigo que agrega el .js de jquery o antes de la definicion del showModalExito()

Deberas revisar html usando las developer tools del browser a la cual accedes con F12 he inspeccionar donde esta ubicado el script dinamico con respecto al resto.

Aqui explica lo que estoy mencionando

[Rendering ASP.NET Script References into the Html Header](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Jan/02/Rendering-ASPNET-Script-References-into-the-Html-Header)

quizas debas cambiar por el `RegisterClientScriptBlock()`

Comment: efectivamente al renderizar la pagina el pone la definicion antes de llamar el .js hay alguna forma de hacer que lo ponga despues?

Comment: por eso mencione RegisterClientScriptBlock, este deberia ponerlo dentro del html con lo cual quedaria despeus de la definicion del js

Comment: Funciono con el RegisterStartupScript lo que hice fue cambiar el lugar donde se referencia el jquery en el htmy para asegurar que quedara antes del script en la renderización.